# UWP Trigger background task

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

Is it possible to trigger a background task by another background task?

Current situation is:

Background task 1 : B1
Trigger 1 : T1 (30 days)
Trigger 2 : T2 (1 hour)

B1 is registered twice using T1 and T2.

Goal:
B1 will execute after 30 days and will also execute every hour on that day until the end of day. Then at end of day, B1 will suspend the every hour execution and the next execution is again 30 days after and the cycle continues.

Is this scenario possible in UWP background tasks?

Comment: You can register a background task from a background task, but not trigger its immediate execution. If I read your question correctly you are really asking about register, not trigger - am I correct?

Comment: Basically yes, that is my question. But how can I do this? Also if my PC is turned off will the timer for the task resets?

Comment: When the 30d task runs you can just register a new TimerTrigger with a 60min frequency. Then you keep count of its activation and once it has been triggered 24 times, you un-register the 60min trigger and re-register the 30d trigger. The registrations should not get reset when you turn off/reboot the PC.

Comment: How can I check the number of activation of the background task? Where should I place it, in the app level or in the background task level?

Comment: You could keep track of it in the ApplicationData.LocalSettings. This way you can access it from both the background task and the main application.